# SQL Server connection string using registry view

Tags: c#, sql-server, registry, database-connection

I am trying to create a SQL Server connection on dynamic basis, means I want to fetch server name, database name and SQL Server user name and password using a registry view.

I am able to get the server name using registry, but I am not able to get the database name, nor the user name and password.

This is my code:

```
public string GetServerName()
{
    string serverName = string.Empty;
    string MachineName = Environment.MachineName;

    using (RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine,registryView))
    {
        RegistryKey registryKey = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL", false);

        if (registryKey != null) 
        {
            foreach (string keyName in registryKey.GetValueNames())
            {
                serverName = $"{MachineName}{"\\"}{keyName}";
            }
        }

        return serverName;
    }
}
```

Comment: The database, username and password data isn't stored in the registry.

Comment: So any other way to get username and password programtically ?

Comment: It would be bad if everyone could just take the usernames from registry. If you're working with the dB, you should be able to connect by your user

Comment: If you are an admin on the local machine you can normally just connect using `Trusted Connection=true`. Side note: for local machines you don't need to use `Environment.MachineName` you can just use `"."`